# Email template if condition in odoo

Tags: python, email, templates, odoo

I done code for email template.I need to check amout value in if condition which is greater or not,but sign ">" does not work.

My code is here:

```
  % if object.amount > 12:
       #some code
  % endif
```

I also tried this.

```
  % if object.amount &gt 12:
       #some code
  % endif
```

how to apply ">" operator in if condition ?

Comment: I am not familiar with oodo, but [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/) could be an alternative solution to email templating for you. It has really good documentation.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution available, You have to achieve your stuff by some other way. for example, You can create new compute field to check your condition.

Comment: Yes,I created one function to check condition and call in template.Its work.

Comment: The function works ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the brackets around the condition

```
% if (object.amount > 12):
       #some code
  % endif
```

Answer (score 0):

A lightweighted approach, that also works, without the need for a separate function:

```
% if (min(object.amount,12) == 12) and (object.amount != 12):
    #some code
% endif
```